# Jenkins - Problem: hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask failed

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a problem : (pending—Waiting for next available executor)

Console log:

```
Timer task hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask@fb3e676 failed
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class hudson.slaves.NodeProperty (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; hudson.slaves.NodeProperty is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @7364985f)
at hudson.model.Node.canTake(Node.java:409)
at hudson.model.Queue$JobOffer.getCauseOfBlockage(Queue.java:276)
at hudson.model.Queue.maintain(Queue.java:1633)
at hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask.doRun(Queue.java:2904)
at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:91)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:58)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Amelia, we need more infromation.  What actions trigger this error.  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be related to a Jenkins bug: [FATAL: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to hudson.slaves.NodeProperty](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59166). Did you recently upgrade your Jenkins?

- Go to the root folder of your Jenkins installation.
- Look in `config.xml` for `<globalNodeProperties>`
- If it looks like this, it probably wasn't correctly upgraded:

```
<globalNodeProperties>
  <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty/>
  <int>2</int>
  <string></string>
  <string></string>
  ...
</globalNodeProperties>
```

- The XML format changed, it should look like this (Note that `int` is no longer a `globalNodeProperty`, a.k.a. the exception your are getting:

```
  <globalNodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator" reference="../../../../../../views/listView/jobNames/comparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>2</int>
          <string></string>
          <string></string>
          ...
        </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
  </globalNodeProperties>
```

Comment: I tried this but after restart the config is overwritten when the jenkins is restarted. I can see in the logs a similar exception throws in the jenkins logs as soon as I visit the configure page. and I also notice that it does not display the environment variables as it used to. Is there any other option to fix this?

Comment: or do you recommend downgrade/upgrade again?

Comment: @SyedAli could you open a new question with your exact stacktrace?

Comment: yes I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602999/jenkins-not-running-any-jobs

Comment: I got it working. The value of comparator that worked for me is `<comparator class="java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>`

Comment: Thanks for this -- saved my bacon.  While I could not edit config.xml successfully, I was able to just remove that section entirely, restart Jenkins, and then add back the global properties using the UI.  I'd have had no idea how to approach this if not for your post -- THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve this by deleting the ruby-runtime plugin.

get into the JENKINS_HOME/plugins and sudo rm -rf ruby-runtime*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).