# Jenkins not running any jobs

Tags: jenkins

I've managed to break Jenkins while trying to fix some other problems. Now whenever I run a job it immediately fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:313)
at hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.buildEnvVars(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.java:85)
at hudson.model.Computer.buildEnvironment(Computer.java:1195)
at hudson.model.Job.getEnvironment(Job.java:385)
at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2419)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getEnvironment(WorkflowRun.java:500)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:112)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:68)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:310)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I found this answer [Jenkins - Problem: hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612355/jenkins-problem-hudson-model-queuemaintaintask-failed) but it suggests rewriting the `config.xml` file. When I do that and reload config from the disk, `config.xml` files gets overwritten by jenkins. I have upgraded jenkins to the latest available version and also updated most of the plugins. I also tried to add back the environment variables through the UI but doing that throws the following exception:

```
2022-01-06 17:21:50.894+0000 [id=10]    WARNING o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler$Context#log: Error while serving https://<jenkins-url>:<port>/configSubmit
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to hudson.model.Describable
        at hudson.util.DescribableList.get(DescribableList.java:126)
        at hudson.util.DescribableList.rebuild(DescribableList.java:168)
        at jenkins.model.GlobalNodePropertiesConfiguration.configure(GlobalNodePropertiesConfiguration.java:25)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.configureDescriptor(Jenkins.java:3846)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:3810)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:400)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
```

which looks similar to the first exception where it is unable to recognize the Integer field. How can I get this configuration fixed?

**How it started**
I had several scheduled jobs running perfectly fine. But suddenly after weeks of successful runs they started to fail without any obvious reason. But they were still running to a certain point. I also had a plugin installed called `build-monitor-plugin` but after installing that I had not restarted jenkins. I decided to restart jenkins to see if that resolves the problem but that landed me into a different set of issues and I never got to figure out why the jobs started to fail after running successfully for several weeks. To find that out I have to resolve the NPE issue first (which I described in the beginning). The folder that had all my jobs now shows a broken view:

[image]

However, I am still able to access the jobs using a direct url to them. This folder had a view added to it using the `build-monitor-plugin` and I suspected it messed up something after the restart. So I uninstalled the plugin but that did not fix the view. I have also manually removed all files related to this plugin but that also does not help. When I visit the folder I see following error in the log:

```
2022-01-06 05:29:47.232+0000 [id=87]    WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID cb5bdf8c-2a97-4360-8f80-95df2c5c719b
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/app/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.319.1.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:42:43: <st:include> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/app/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.319.1.jar!/lib/hudson/projectView.jelly:67:24: <d:invokeBody> `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally managed to fix both issues.

**What happened?**
Sequence of installing the plugin-in `build-monitor-plugin`, restarting Jenkins and then uninstalling the plug-in left some of the files in Jenkins in a corrupted state. A state from which Jenkins version `2.263.3` was unable to recover even though it kept on recreating the files but every time it was creating the same corrupted files again.

**Corrupted Files**
There were two files that got corrupted and both are named `config.xml`. First one is in the top most level directory of Jenkins. It is supposed to be as follows in case you have `environment variables`:

```
  <globalNodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>2</int> <!-- This number indicates how many key/value pairs will follow it -->
          <string></string>
          <string></string>
          ...
        </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
  </globalNodeProperties>
```

Something similar was also suggested in [Jenkins - Problem: hudson.model.Queue$MaintainTask failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612355/jenkins-problem-hudson-model-queuemaintaintask-failed) but the value of `<comparator>` class mentioned there did not work. I figured out the correct value by installing a separate instance of Jenkins and comparing the new config.xml with the old one.

Similarly the other `config.xml` that was broken was for the folder which was not showing up properly as can be seen in question. For that I created another folder and compared it's config.xml with the broken one and found following two lines missing from the `<folderViews>`:

```
  ...
  <folderViews>
    ...
    <primaryView>All</primaryView>
    <tabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  </folderViews>
  ...
```

Adding these two lines resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you, your hard work saved me!  I started getting the same exception you did after an upgrade and couldn't get Jenkins working again even after rolling everything back. Your self-answer told me what to do and I replaced the corrupted `config.xml` with a good version from `config-history/`. I highly recommend the [Job Configuration History plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory/) because it's the reason I had an older copy of `config.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on this answer since we just had a very similar error pop up and we had the `build-monitor-plugin` plugin installed, too:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.buildEnvVars(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Computer.buildEnvironment(Computer.java:1210)
    at hudson.model.Job.getEnvironment(Job.java:385)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:334)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2419)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:943)
    at CUSTOM_PLUGIN
```

I immediately thought our custom plugin was to blame but reverting to the previous stable version did not change this behavior. Then, finding @Syed Ali's answer, I looked at our `config.xml` files but they seemed fine.

The problem was that, in the *Configuration* of the administrative section, the *Environment Variables* section's checkbox was checked but no key-value pairs had been added. For some reason, unchecking that option fixed any related problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem but for me it was about the `<nodeProperties>` node in `config.xml`. I had an empty value there (some bug in Jenkins plugin probably set `MAVEN_OPTS` without value). If I replaced it by empty `<nodeProperties/>` I worked for me, but if I need to setup something I have to remove it manually.

Comment: This currently looks more like a question than an answer. Please rephrase it to be more explicit: "*If you have … then try to …*"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34487822)